How should I write this in my essay: "Team A is trailing 1-2 or one-two"?

Team A was trailing 1-2 after the first half.

Q1: Should I write one-two instead of 1-2? It's an academic essay.
Q2: How should I pronounce 1-2 (a score in sports)? Is it one two or one to two?

Technically it should be an en dash (–). Not something the average person would notice or even know, but you can get it right for your essay.

I don’t think it’s particularly common to spell out scores, so I would use numerals.

And scores are most often read as “n to m.” But when a score is being used as a modifier attributively, the to is often left out, as in They played to a ten ten tie. (Here I have not punctuated the score at all so as to convey unambiguously the pronunciation.)

And @the-baby-is-you’s point is supported by, for instance The Chicago Manual of Style. Instead of the hyphens that you used, it is preferable to use en dashes. Thus not “1-2,” but “1–2.”

And, it is custom always to put the higher score first. Thus not “1–2,” but “2—1.”

In some sports/countries/leagues you put the home team first, in others you put the higher score first (and in tennis you put the person currently serving first, so there are probably other subtleties in other sports).

AP style mandates figures exclusively and a hyphen not an en dash. The hyphen is because AP limits the character set because historically it was used with various simple terminals and transmission devices in the pre-Unicode era.

Sports scores always use numerals separated by an en-dash (–)
So, 1–2, not one–two.
However, normal usage is to put the winning score first, so, unless you have a good reason for emphasising that Team A was trailing, a better construction is “Team B was leading 2–1 …”. Context matters here; for example if your essay is about Team A in particular, telling the score with them first is fine. Also, reporting on scores in a league have their own conventions - some always list the home team’s score first, some the away team, and some the winning/leading team.
As for speaking the score, either is fine unless it’s ambiguous. So 20–4 should be “twenty to four” because “twenty four” could mean 24.

At least in British English, another construct for the losing team is something like "Team A was 2 - 1 down at half time"

Thank you! So, "Team A is trailing 1-2" and "Team A is trailing 2-1" are both fine if I only want to talk about team A, right?
